# Android Maps V2 unable to scroll smoothly - creates blur in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-maps-v2

Ive been working on integrating maps v2 into my application, ive successfully done it and am able to visualize things on both device and emulator, but when i try to add some widgets below map in the layout im unable to scroll smoothly and maps create blurred impressions on the screen, See below images when i tried to scroll with maps fragment embedded

[image: Initial image before scrolling]

[image: Image after scrolling]

In the above image i am actually supposed to have a smooth transition on scroll to show two buttons. But im aware that somethings wrong, can some one please suggest me a solution? Many Thanks in advance

activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="730dp" >

        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            facebook:confirm_logout="false"
            facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />

        <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
            android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            facebook:preset_size="normal" >
        </com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/greeting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profilePicture"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="345dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicture"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapClear"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mapSet"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mapSet"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/greeting"
            android:text="Clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapSet"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/greeting"
            android:layout_below="@+id/map"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Set" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fuelTest"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/profilePicture"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mapSet"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="get fuel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fuelLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fuelTest"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fuelTest"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/greeting"
            android:text="@string/fuellevel"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/post"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/greeting"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/greeting"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:text="post" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you'd better not put the map fragment inside a ScrollView, the map itself can be considered as a scrolling view and putting scrolling views inside another scrolling view always messes up things in Android.

Comment: ok then is there any alternate solution to fix this? i mean how to i restrict map inside a box or a frame?

Answer (score 2):

Don't put a scrollable view inside a ScrollView since it induces optimization and ux problems. E.g.: It might be confusing if scrolling vertically changes the map's camera position instead of scrolling down the view. If the user has to be able to interact with the map (as the configuration of your mapview implies) put it on the top and add widgets below. If your widgets don't contain elements which can vary in height largely (such as descriptive TextViews) use a vertical LinearLayout and assign 30 percent of the weight to the map and the rest to the widgets. Depending on how large in height your widgets could become, you can still use a ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <!-- put your widgets here -->
        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

If your users wouldn't have to interact with the map, you could also retrieve a corresponding map tile via [Google's static map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example) and simply display it in an ImageView. Example:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the maps demo for multi maps.